# pandas ewm.std calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to verify the ewm.std calculations of pandas so that I can implement a one step update for my code. Here is the complete description of the problem with code.

```
mrt = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
N = 100
a = 2/(1+N)
bias = (2-a)/2/(1-a)
x = mrt.iloc[-2]
ma = mrt.ewm(span=N).mean().iloc[-3]
var = mrt.ewm(span=N).var().iloc[-3]
ans = mrt.ewm(span=N).std().iloc[-2]
print(np.sqrt( bias*(1-a) * (var + a * (x- ma)**2)), ans)
```

> (1.1352524643949702, 1.1436193844674576)

I have used standard formulation. Could somebody tell me why the two values should not be same? i.e. how is pandas calculating the exponentially weighted std?

EDIT: After Julien's answer - let me give one more use case. I am plotting the ratio of the var calculated by pandas and using the formula I inferred from the Cython code of pandas ewm-covariance. This ratio should be 1. (I am guessing there is a problem with  my formula, if somebody can point it out).

```
mrt = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))

N = 100
a = 2./(1+N)
bias = (2-a)/2./(1-a)
mewma = mrt.ewm(span=N).mean()

var_pandas = mrt.ewm(span=N).var()
var_calculated = bias * (1-a) * (var_pandas.shift(1) + a * (mrt-mewma.shift(1))**2)

(var_calculated/var_pandas).plot()
```

The plot shows the problem clearly.

[image: plot of the ratio after the initial values are removed]

EDIT 2: By trial and error, I figured out the right formula:

```
var_calculated = (1-a) * (var_pandas.shift(1) + bias * a * (mrt-mewma.shift(1))**2)
```

But I am not convinced that it should be the right one! Can somebody put light on that?

Comment: potential duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924377/does-pandas-calculate-ewm-wrong)?

Comment: @JulienMarrec No. I can verify the ewma exactly. I am getting trumped at ewmstd.

Comment: ewm is defined here: [window.py#L1387](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window.py#L1387).

ewm.std call is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window.py#L1555).- and then goes to _zqrst [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/window.py#L1761)

Comment: Yup! I looked at the cython code as well. That is where I derived the bias term from. There can be some difference due to how pandas implements it, but the order of difference here is much more than that would imply.

Comment: There are (broken) equations in the [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#exponentially-weighted-windows). I assume you've read that too.

Comment: Yes I did read all of it. Somebody would be able to use my example to find where I went wrong, is my hope. It's a simple thing but is so baffling that I can't get it exactly right!

Comment: isn't bias=False by default? (Away from computer)

Comment: bias toggle will not affect things at second decimal place for longer series. I have tried those things as well to exclude that as the cause of the order of error I show here in the example. There is something more fundamentally wrong in one of the calculations, most probably mine.

Comment: I am trying to find the ewm.std formula as well.  I copy-pasted your code (with your edited calculation) and got [this](https://i.imgur.com/7CDGgxG.png) result.  Definitely not the "exact match" that you mention below.  Has something changed in a recent version of Pandas?

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation of the `ewm` function, the default flag `adjust=True` is used. As it is explained in the links below, the exponentially weighted moving values are not computed using the recursive relations, but instead using weights. This is justified, particularly for the cases when the length of the series is small.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8861

This means that the `ewma` and `ewmvar` are computed as normal weighted average and var with the weights being the exponentially decreasing factors

```
mrt_array = np.array(mrt.tolist())
M = len(mrt_array)
weights = (1-a)**np.arange(M-1, -1, -1) # This is reverse order to match Series order
ewma = sum(weights * mrt_array) / sum(weights)
bias = sum(weights)**2 / (sum(weights)**2 - sum(weights**2))
ewmvar = bias * sum(weights * (mrt_array - ewma)**2) / sum(weights)
ewmstd = np.sqrt(ewmvar)
```

Comment: Thank you. Used this code to answer similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809786/pandas-ewm-var-and-std/62434023#62434023). upvoted.

Comment: How do you derive this formula theoretically? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your question actually actually reduces to how pandas calculate `ewm.var()`

```
In [1]:
(np.sqrt(mrt.ewm(span=span).var()) == mrt.ewm(span=span).std())[1:].value_counts()

Out[1]:
True    999
dtype: int64
```

So in your example above: `ans == np.sqrt(mrt.ewm(span=N).var().iloc[-2])`.

To investigate how it calculates ewmvar(), it does it by calling [emcov](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/window.pyx#L1547) with `input_x=input_y=mrt`

---

If we check for the first elements:

```
mrt.ewm(span=span).var()[:2].values
> array([nan,  0.00555309])
```

Now, using the emcov routine, and applying it to our specific case:

```
x0 = mrt.iloc[0]
x1 = mrt.iloc[1]
x2 = mrt.iloc[2]

# mean_x and mean_y are both the same, here we call it y
# This is the same as mrt.ewm(span=span).mean(), I verified that too
y0 = x0
# y1 = mrt.ewm(span=span).mean().iloc[1]
y1 = ((1-alpha)*y0 + x1)/(1+(1-alpha))
#y2 = (((1-alpha)**2+(1-alpha))*y1 + x2) / (1 + (1-alpha) + (1-alpha)**2) 

cov0 = 0

cov1 = (((1-alpha) * (cov0 + ((y0 - y1)**2))) +
                (1 * ((x1 - y1)**2))) / (1 + (1-alpha))

# new_wt = 1, sum_wt0 = (1-alpha), sum_wt2 = (1-alpha)**2
sum_wt = 1+(1-alpha)
sum_wt2 =1+(1-alpha)**2


numerator = sum_wt * sum_wt # (1+(1-alpha))^2 = 1 + 2(1-alpha) + (1-alpha)^2
denominator = numerator - sum_wt2 # # 2*(1-alpha)


print(np.nan,cov1*(numerator / denominator))

>(nan, 0.0055530905712123432)
```

Comment: Thanks Julien. I think what you did is fine. Can you confirm if you get the same equality for the last step? Please see the edit above in the question.

Comment: Yes, confirmed.

Comment: Thanks! So there is some trouble with my formula then. By trial and error I found that the correct formula should be var_calculated = (1-a) * (var_pandas.shift(1) + bias * a * (mrt-mewma.shift(1))**2). This gives exact match! But I am not sure why :) Thanks for all the trouble @Julien

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If you could at least upvote if that was helpful I'd appreciate it

Comment: I did. but it doesn't show up because I have less than 15 reputation!

Comment: @ma327: you should be able to accept this answer, by clicking on the tick/check mark to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @[kosnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754262/pandas-ewm-std-calculation) for the answer above. Copy-pasted your code below and build it up on it to answer the question here. Thus calculated exponential moving variance and standard deviation for entire dataset. The calculated values match with the output of `.ewm()`.

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
mrt = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=mrt, columns=['data'])


# Initialize 
N = 3 # Span
a = 2./(1+N) # Alpha

# Use .evm() to calculate 'exponential moving variance' directly
var_pandas = df.ewm(span=N).var()
std_pandas = df.ewm(span=N).std()

# Initialize variable
varcalc=[]
stdcalc=[]

# Calculate exponential moving variance
for i in range(0,len(df.data)):

    z = np.array(df.data.iloc[0:i+1].tolist())

    # Get weights: w
    n = len(z)
    w = (1-a)**np.arange(n-1, -1, -1) # This is reverse order to match Series order

    # Calculate exponential moving average
    ewma = np.sum(w * z) / np.sum(w)

    # Calculate bias
    bias = np.sum(w)**2 / (np.sum(w)**2 - np.sum(w**2))

    # Calculate exponential moving variance with bias
    ewmvar = bias * np.sum(w * (z - ewma)**2) / np.sum(w)

    # Calculate standard deviation
    ewmstd = np.sqrt(ewmvar)

    # Append
    varcalc.append(ewmvar)
    stdcalc.append(ewmstd)
    #print('ewmvar:',ewmvar)


#varcalc
df['var_pandas'] = var_pandas
df['varcalc'] = varcalc
df['std_pandas'] = std_pandas
df['stdcalc'] = stdcalc
df
```

[image]