# Vectorized implementation of exponentially weighted moving standard deviation using R?

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average, standard-deviation, quantitative-finance

I am trying to implement a vectorized exponentially weighted moving standard deviation using R. Is this the correct approach?

```
ewma <- function (x, alpha) {
  c(stats::filter(x * alpha, 1 - alpha, "recursive", init = x[1]))
}
ewmsd <- function(x, alpha) {
  sqerror <- na.omit((x - lag(ewma(x, alpha)))^2)
  ewmvar <- c(stats::filter(sqerror * alpha, 1 - alpha, "recursive", init = 0))
  c(NA, sqrt(ewmvar))
}
```

I'm guessing it's not, since its output is different from Python's `pandas.Series.ewm.std()` function.

When I run

```
ewmsd(x = 0:9, alpha = 0.96)
```

the output is

```
 [1]        NA 0.2236068 0.4874679 0.7953500 1.1353903 1.4993855 1.8812961 2.2764708 2.6812160 3.0925367
```

However, with

```
pd.Series(range(10)).ewm(alpha = 0.96).std()
```

the output is

```
0         NaN
1    0.707107
2    0.746729
3    0.750825
4    0.751135
5    0.751155
6    0.751156
7    0.751157
8    0.751157
9    0.751157
```

Comment: Look at package “zoo”.

Comment: At what function, specifically? I don't think "zoo" has functions for calculating exponentially weighted moving statistics. `rollapply` would not work in this case.

Comment: I don’t see why rollapply could not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation for Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html), the `pandas.Series.ewm()` function receives an `adjust` parameter, which defaults to `TRUE`. When `adjust == TRUE`, the exponentially weighted moving average from `pandas.Series.ewm.mean()` is calculated through weights, not recursively. Naturally, this affects the standard deviation output as well. See [this Github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8861) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754262/pandas-ewm-std-calculation) for more info.

Here's a vectorized solution in R:

```
   ewmsd <- function(x, alpha) {
      n <- length(x)
      sapply(
        1:n,
        function(i, x, alpha) {
          y <- x[1:i]
          m <- length(y)
          weights <- (1 - alpha)^((m - 1):0)
          ewma <- sum(weights * y) / sum(weights)
          bias <- sum(weights)^2 / (sum(weights)^2 - sum(weights^2))
          ewmsd <- sqrt(bias * sum(weights * (y - ewma)^2) / sum(weights))
        },
        x = x,
        alpha = alpha
      )
    }
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a `stats::filter` (recursive) solution for `ewmsd`?