# Replicate ewm pandas function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate ewm python (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) function in R but without success.

Here is the python code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0:100]})
df.ewm(span=100).std()
```

I can't get same (or similar) results in R.

Comment: What is it you have tried in R that doesn't work?

Comment: I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585015/vectorized-implementation-of-exponentially-weighted-moving-standard-deviation-us but is extremely slow.

Comment: And I have also tried `frollapply(as.vector(df0), n = 100, FUN = function(x) sqrt(Hmisc::wtd.var(x)))`

Comment: here's R code for doing so: https://gist.github.com/assuncaolfi/5581528021ac75247a4a1f1c0c3fe12f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vectorized implementation of exponentially weighted moving standard deviation using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585015/vectorized-implementation-of-exponentially-weighted-moving-standard-deviation-us)

Comment: @tester, I tried this code but it is so slow that I didn't even wait it to finish. Python code takes only one or 2  seconds. ANd I am not even sure it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have change the code from [Vectorized implementation of exponentially weighted moving standard deviation using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585015/vectorized-implementation-of-exponentially-weighted-moving-standard-deviation-us) to make it much fater:

```
f <- function(y, m, alpha) {
  weights <- (1 - alpha)^((m - 1):0)
  ewma <- sum(weights * y) / sum(weights)
  bias <- sum(weights)^2 / (sum(weights)^2 - sum(weights^2))
  ewmsd <- sqrt(bias * sum(weights * (y - ewma)^2) / sum(weights))
  ewmsd
} 
test <- frollapply(df0, 1000, function(x) f(x, 1000, alpha))
```

where df0 is df with one column or vector.

Results are the same (to 5 decimal place) as reults generated from python function.