# Why does the definition of standard deviation differ from Pandas calculation for exponentially weighted windows?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Given the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Definition_of_population_values) of standard deviation as:
the square root of the expectation of X-squared minus the expectation of X, squared;
why do the following two calculations of exponentially weighted standard deviation not result in the same values?

```
import numpy
import pandas
x = pandas.Series(numpy.random.default_rng(0).normal(size=1000))
com = 2
a = x.ewm(com).std()
b = numpy.sqrt((x**2).ewm(com).mean() - (x.ewm(com).mean())**2)

pandas.concat([a,b], axis=1).tail(5)
```

Output:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 995 | 1.535113 | 1.373047 |
| 996 | 1.302008 | 1.164551 |
| 997 | 1.320120 | 1.180751 |
| 998 | 1.215099 | 1.086818 |
| 999 | 1.002668 | 0.896814 |

Comment: FYI, `a/b` is a constant.

Comment: @QuangHoang, interesting, thank you. Are you able to describe why this is?

Comment: Just digged into the code and realized that it's due to [`bias=False`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Unbiased_sample_standard_deviation) as default. Passing `bias=True`  to `std(bias=True)` gives the same answer as `b`

Comment: Yes thank you, that makes `a` like `b`. But how should I modify the calculation in `b` to make it like `a`? How do I bias correct the calculation in `b`?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Most ewm's methods are native C. I did look into [github code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2f8d0a36703e81e4dca52ca9fe4f58c910c1b304/pandas/core/window/ewm.py), which is somewhat equivalent to the signature.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I don't, hence the comments. I do think that there is a bias coefficient, just that I don't know what it is or how to calculate it.

Comment: @handlist [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236294/4238408) seems to show the bias coefficient. You can check it out.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you very much! From that link I was able to derive the bias correction term of sqrt(1+(2*com))