# What value to use for halflife in pandas ewm function? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

I have a Series of data, each reflects a value that was taken every 7 days.

I'd like to calculate the exponential moving average of that Series using a half-life of 3 days. What value should I use for the halflife attribute in the ewm function call?

```
s = pd.Series([232848661129,327042265468,235595837210,220903949498,287582315011])
s.ewm(halflife=7/3,min_periods=0,adjust=True,ignore_na=False).mean()
```

What halflife value would be correct here? Is halflife=7/3 correct?

I'm not sure how to make this work.

Comment: This isn't really a question about coding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924377/does-pandas-calculate-ewm-wrong

Comment: Why would it be 7/3, and not 3?

Comment: Wouldnt halflife=3 mean that after 3 values the weight will be halfed? In my case 3 values represent 21 days, not 3 days