# Simple Python Pandas EMA (ewma)?

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote some code to build my own EMA/MACD, but have decided to give Pandas a try instead.

I am using this website below as a basic understanding of EMA and trying to get pandas to give me the same answers to be sure I am using pandas correctly:

http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:technical_indicators:moving_averages

And here is the chart with the data that Im working with.

[image]

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work, but it gives me different output than the 10-day EMA column

```
import pandas as pd

data=[22.27,22.19,22.08,22.17,22.18,22.13,22.23,22.43,22.24,22.29,22.15,22.39,22.38,22.61,23.36,24.05,23.75,23.83]

df=pd.Series(data)

pd.ewma(df, span=10)
```

I've also tried this with no luck.

```
pd.ewma(df, span=10, min_periods=10)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Pandas calculate ewm wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924377/does-pandas-calculate-ewm-wrong)

Answer (score 9):

Coincidentally, this question was asked and answered here: [Does Pandas calculate ewm wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924377/does-pandas-calculate-ewm-wrong)

Check out @chrisb's answer there. To compute the EWM as described in the article you're studying:

1. manually compute the first valid simple MA to serve as a starting point for EWA
2. run pandas' EWM with `adjust=False`

Answer (score 4):

According to [calculate-exponential-moving-average-with-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812198/calculate-exponential-moving-average-with-pandas) self-answer, and assuming that `close` serie is corresponding to the `close price`, you may use this to get the `EMA 10`: *(change the span to what you want if you want another span)*

```
df['ema10'] = pd.Series.ewm(df['close'], span=10).mean()
```