# calculate Exponential Moving Average with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to calculate ema with pandas but the result is not good.
I try 2 techniques to calculate :

The first technique is the panda's function `ewn`:

```
window = 100
c = 2 / float(window + 1)
df['100ema'] = df['close'].ewm(com=c).mean()
```

But the last result of this function gives. `2695.4` but the real result is `2656.2`

The second technique is

```
window = 100
c = 2 / float(window + 1)
df['100sma'] = df['close'].rolling(window).mean()
df['100ema'] = (c * df['close']) + ((1 - c) * df['100sma'])
```

The result is `2649.1` it's closer than first technique but is always not good

The sma function give the good result

** EDIT  **

The response is

```
df['100ema'] = pd.Series.ewm(df['close'], span=window).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your native pandas response !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to calculate EWMA or any technical indicator in Python, I recommend using [ta-lib](https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib).

Comment: nice a want use this lib instead of breaking my head

Comment: I spent days and was willing to spend days more implementing like 20 of these on my own. thank you. Of all of the things I googled in my work. "Python TA library" wasnt one of them

Comment: df is my dataframe and 'close' is the closing price of the stock. I calculated ema for various timeperiods using these instructions:
>>> df['ema12'] = talib.EMA(df['close'],timeperiod=12)
>>> df['ema18'] = talib.EMA(df['close'],timeperiod=18)
>>> df['ema25'] = talib.EMA(df['close'],timeperiod=25)

Answer (score 2):

```
expwighted_avg = ts_log.ewm(halflife=12).mean()
```

where 'ts_log' is dataframe or series of Time Series