# finding minimum value between 2 conditions in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am very new to python. I have a long question below. I would really appreciate it if you guys could help me.

I have a large dataframe of stockprice data with 
df.columns = ['open','high','low','close']

I have also computed two exponential moving averages based on the closing price everyday - 5EMA and 10EMA

When a moving average cross over happens, i.e the 5EMA > 10EMA today but the 
5EMA < 10EMA yesterday, i have df['cross']='cross' to signify that a crossover has happened.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("Nifty.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['5EMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=5).mean()

df['10EMA'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=10).mean()

condition1 = df['5EMA'].shift(1) < df['10EMA'].shift(1)

condition2 = df['5EMA'] > df['10EMA']

df['cross'] = np.where(condition1 & condition2, 'cross', None)

print(df)
```

I need a column df['min'] which finds the minimum value of df['low'] between this df['cross']='cross' and previous df['cross]='cross'.

I need a column df['check'] such as,
df['check'] = 'up', if current df['min'] > previous df['min']

Here is a sample output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZnzd.png)

In the sample output, when the third 'cross' occurs, the minimum value of df['low'] between the third cross and second cross(in this case '11') is GREATER THAN the minimum value of df['low'] between the first cross and the second cross(in this case '8'). So, df['check']='up'

When the fourth 'cross' occurs, the minimum value of df['low'] between the fourth cross and third cross(in this case '10') is NOT GREATER THAN the minimum value of df['low'] between the second cross and the third cross(in this case '11'). So, df['check']='down'

I need to generate the value of df['check'] continually like this everytime when df['cross']='cross'
​

Comment: Can you provide a sample input/output to help us understand your problem? For instance, what does your input/output `df` looks like.

Comment: I strongly suggest you put the second question "I also want..." in a separate Q&A. Each question should only be one question.

Comment: Hi, I have added a sample output as a link. are you able to open the sample output?

Answer (score 0):

Python's `if` / `else` construct does not work in a vectorised way with Pandas / NumPy. Here you can use `np.where` for column-wise operations:

```
# CORRECT
df['cross'] = np.where(df['CO'], 'cross', None)

# INCORRECT
# df['cross'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'cross' if (df['CO'] is True) else None, axis=1)
```

If you are keen on a row-wise loop, it is possible but *inefficient*:

```
df['cross'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'cross' if row['CO'] else None, axis=1)
```