# Is there a way to get Pandas ewm to function on fixed windows?

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, weighted-average

I am trying to use [Pandas ewm function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html) to calculating exponentially weighted moving averages. However i've noticed that information seems to carry through your entire time series. What this means is that every data point's MA is dependant on a different number of previous data points. Therefore the ewm function at every data point is mathematically different.

I think some here had a similar question

[Does Pandas calculate ewm wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924377/does-pandas-calculate-ewm-wrong)

But i did try their method, and i am not getting functionality i want.

```
 def EMA(arr, window):
     sma = arr.rolling(window=window, min_periods=window).mean()[:window]
     rest = arr[window:]
     return pd.concat([sma, rest]).ewm(com=window, adjust=False).mean()


 a = pd.DataFrame([x for x in range(100)])
 print(list(EMA(a, 10)[0])[-1])
 print(list(EMA(a[50:], 10)[0])[-1])
```

In this example, i have an array of 1 through 100. I calculate moving averages on this array, and array of 50-100. The last moving average should be the same, since i am using only a window of 10. But when i run this code i get two different values, indicating that ewm is indeed dependent on the entire series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you are asking for ewm in a rolling window, which means, every 10 rows return a single number. If that is the case, then we can use a stride trick:

**Edit**: update function works on series only

```
def EMA(arr, window=10, alpha=0.5):
    ret = pd.Series(index=arr.index, name=arr.name)

    arr=np.array(arr)
    l = len(arr)
    stride = arr.strides[0]

    ret.iloc[window-1:] = (pd.DataFrame(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, 
                                                                       (l-window+1,window), 
                                                                       (stride,stride)))
                          .T.ewm(alpha)
                          .mean()
                          .iloc[-1]
                          .values
                           )
    return ret
```

Test:

```
a = pd.Series([x for x in range(100)])

EMA(a).tail(2)
# 98    97.500169
# 99    98.500169
# Name: 9, dtype: float64

EMA(a[:50]).tail(2)
# 98    97.500169
# 99    98.500169
# Name: 9, dtype: float64

EMA(a, 2).tail(2)
98    97.75
99    98.75
dtype: float64
```

Test on random data:

```
a = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0,1,10000))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
a.plot(ax=ax)
EMA(a,alpha=0.99, window=2).plot(ax=ax)
EMA(a,alpha=0.99, window=1500).plot(ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

Output: we can see that the larger window (green) is less volatile than the smaller window (orange).

[image]

Comment: I'm actually not quite sure if this is what i'm looking for. Adjusting the window looks to just offset the data, it doesn't increase the amount of data points that a single moving average takes into account.

Comment: Are you sure? `EMA(a,window=2).tail(10)` gives: `98    98.75` and `90    90.75`

Comment: Adjusting the window should smooth the data but it looks to just offset it. If i do a shift on the data, i see that it lines up.

Comment: Your data is linear, moving average over a fixed window would just shift it. Try the code on `a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,3,100))`.

Comment: @learningthemachine see update. Note that the function now works for series only.

Comment: I think the volatility is only being reduced by the alpha coefficient. If you just change the window size i get the same results.

Comment: Actually, the included picture uses `alpha=0.99` for both windows. Updated.

Comment: That does indeed look to be working as i wanted it to at first glance. I'll have to do some more testing but it should be good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be possible in pandas 1.5 with a mix of rolling, and win_type:

```py
pd.Series.rolling(window=10, win_type='exponential').mean(tau=0.5, center=10, sym=False)
```

I use a non symetric exponential window centered at the same size of the window in order to have a exponential function decaying towards the past.

This yields the same results as the EMA function provided by Quang Hoang.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def EMA(arr, window=10, alpha=0.5):
    ret = pd.Series(index=arr.index, name=arr.name, dtype='float64')

    arr=np.array(arr)
    l = len(arr)
    stride = arr.strides[0]

    ret.iloc[window-1:] = (pd.DataFrame(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, 
                                                                       (l-window+1,window), 
                                                                       (stride,stride)))
                          .T.ewm(alpha)
                          .mean()
                          .iloc[-1]
                          .values
                           )
    return ret

a = pd.Series([x for x in range(100)])

custom=EMA(a)
builtin= a.rolling(window=10, win_type='exponential').mean(tau=0.5, center=10, sym=False)

custom=custom.plot.line(label="Custom EMA")
builtin.plot.line(label="Built-in EMA")
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by working with the formula for exponential smoothing by cancelling the lagged terms. The formula can be found on the [ewm page](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html).
The following code demonstrates that no memory is left after adjustment. For every point, the fixed window of information used is `L=1000`. And the factor `f` should be included if one desires to have the equivalent for the `adjust=True` version (for `adjust=False` just get rid of the `f` factor).

```
srs1=pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=100000))
alpha=0.02
em1=srs1.ewm(alpha=alpha,adjust=False).mean()
L=1000

f=1-(1-alpha)**np.clip(np.arange(em1.shape[0]),0,L)
em1_=(em1-em1.shift(L)*(1-alpha)**L)/f


S=1001
em2=srs1[S:].ewm(alpha=alpha,adjust=False).mean()
f=1-(1-alpha)**np.clip(np.arange(em2.shape[0]),0,L)
em2_=(em2-em2.shift(L)*(1-alpha)**L)/f

print((em2_[:10000]-em1_[S:S+10000]).abs().max())
```