# Does ewm() weight within rolling windows or the entire column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation, exponential, rolling-computation

I am having trouble understanding how the following `ewm()` function is working from trial and reading the docs, can anyone help explain?

I am trying to use the following line to exponentially weight correlation within each rolling window.

`df['col'].ewm(alpha=0.02, min_periods=10).corr(df['col2'])`

My question is:
Does this exponentially weight within windows of 10 rows on a rolling basis? if not, how can this be done?

Comment: it is well explained here in the documentation https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/computation/computation5.html, you can check with the formulas in excel and compare the result with pandas ewm result to deep your understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min_periods` only make sure you have at least 10 data points (rows) before making the calculation. It wouldn't change the outputs where the `min_periods` is met. Here's an example:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(20))

# with min_periods
s1 = s.ewm(alpha=0.5, min_periods=5).corr(s)

# without min_periods
s2 = s.ewm(alpha=0.5).corr(s)

# compare the results
(s1 == s2)
```

Output:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
16     True
17     True
18     True
19     True
dtype: bool
```

As you can see, the first 4 rows are `False` because `s1` also has first items being `NaN` due to `min_periods`.

**TLDR**: No, it only masks the first few items as `NaN`. It stills computes the weighted on the entire column, doesn't shift anything.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, I have updated the question slightly as I'm still unsure how I can use these pandas' functions to exponentially weight within each rolling window.

Comment: @np2020 See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012189/is-there-a-way-to-get-pandas-ewm-to-function-on-fixed-windows/58013016#58013016). It is for `mean()`, but I think you can make it work for `corr`.